# Dual Monitor & cursor

Tags: mouse, monitor, cursor

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 with dual monitor set up. I'm running unity with launcher only on my primary monitor with the auto hide option disabled. So my launcher appears on my primary monitor forever. I used to have my secondary monitor to my right and it all worked perfectly.

Recently I changed the orientation of my monitors such that my secondary monitor is towards my left. In-order to bring the mouse pointer to the monitor on my left I need to move it the right end of my primary screen. To be short my mouse pointer moves only towards the right of my primary monitor and its not moving to the left.

I looked for settings in ubuntu tweak app and CCSM. I couldn't find one to change the setting. Is there any way to change this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: please post /etc/xorg.conf

Comment: @zuberuber The file 'xorg.conf' is in the /etc/X11 directory.

Answer (score 9):

#### Goto `System > Preferences > Display`. Should show a window similar than the following:

[image]

### Then you should drag one monitor to the other side.

Comment: I missed the trick there.. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Click & hold one monitor and then drag this monitor and drop in the other side (if choose LEFT, drop on RIGHT)

Comment: @user79746 Please remember to *accept* the answer you deem most helpful.